# Parameterized Variables for use in Assertion Groovy Script

Tags: sql, groovy, soapui, assertions

Essentially, I am using SoapUI for some smoke testing and have created an assertion script that checks if there is data within an SQL database.

This test has to be ran on three different environments, each with their individual database credentials.

What I would like to do is create a Custom Property (or set of custom properties) in the test class that holds the three sets of database information to allow a tester to simply select which environment they're testing rather than having to change the hard-coded assertion script.

The code:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql    
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

def con = Sql.newinstance('"server", "user",
                              "pass", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"')

def res = con.rows("select * from table1 where message_in = 'Bang'")

log.info(res[0])

con.close()

assert res[0] != null
```

Comment: Is this run in command line?

Comment: No, SoapUI has a Groovy Script editor that can be executed from a Test Case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should firstly create global variables, to do this please follow the below steps:

- Click onto the project link which is located at the left hand side of the screen as a tree view menu.
- Click to the 'Custom Properties' tab, at the left down side
- Click onto the + icon to add new property.

After creating the variables for the DB connection you can access them within the groovy script as below.

```
import groovy.sql.Sql    
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

def dbServer = context.expand( '${#Project#dbServer}' )
def dbUser = context.expand( '${#Project#dbUser}' )
def dbPass = context.expand( '${#Project#dbPass}' )


def con = Sql.newinstance('dbServer, dbUser,
                              dbPass, "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"')

def res = con.rows("select * from table1 where message_in = 'Bang'")

log.info(res[0])

con.close()

assert res[0] != null
```